# Google Map not dropping pin with intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using Implicit Intent to open a location in Google Maps. Is there any way to drop a pin on the location?

here is my code:

```
Uri geoLocationUri = Uri.parse("geo:" + 0 + "," + 0 + "q?=" + focalPoint.getY() + "," + focalPoint.getX() );
Intent googleMapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoLocationUri);
googleMapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(googleMapIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrectly placed your `?` in the query, try:

```
Uri geoLocationUri = Uri.parse("geo:" + 0 + "," + 0 + "?q=" + focalPoint.getY() + "," + focalPoint.getX());
```

the [Google Maps Location Search Intent docs for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#location_search) for your reference.